A question regarding entropy change in a cyclic process
I was studying thermodynamics and my textbook said that for an irreversible process in a closed system,$$dS \geq \frac{\delta Q}{T}\tag{1}$$ which can also be written as, $$\Delta S = S_2-S_1 \geq \int_1^2\frac{\delta Q}{T}\tag{2}$$
This means the net change in entropy is greater than the integral of $\delta Q / T$ evaluated for that process. However, from Clausius inequality, we know that $$\oint\frac{\delta Q}{T} \leq 0\tag{3}$$ Since there is entropy $S_{gen}$ that is generated in an irreversible process, the net change in entropy is $$\Delta S_{sys} = S_2-S_1 = \int_1^2\frac{\delta Q}{T} + S_{gen}\tag{4}$$
My question is if we take the cyclic integral of this equation, we have,$$\oint dS_{sys} = \oint\frac{\delta Q}{T} + \oint dS_{gen}\tag{5}$$
Since entropy change in an irreversible process must always be positive, the magnitude of $\oint dS_{gen}$ must be greater than the magnitude of $\oint \delta Q/T$ and thus making $\oint dS_{sys}$ overall positive, correct?
Please correct me if I am wrong, thank you!


Since entropy change in an irreversible process must always be
positive

The total entropy change of the system plus surroundings must always be positive for an irreversible process, not the entropy change of the system alone. This applies to an irreversible process and for an irreversible cycle.
But for a cycle, the entropy change of the system must be zero since entropy is a state function. Thus for an irreversible cycle all the entropy increase must occur in the surroundings.
In terms of the Clausius inequality, this means that over a cycle the entropy transferred to the system is less than the entropy transferred to the surroundings.
Hope this helps.

For a closed cycle, starting state of the system = ending state of the system:  $\oint\Delta S_{sys} = 0$ because entropy is a state function, and since $\oint S_{gen}\ge 0$ always you must also have
$$\oint\frac{\delta Q}{T} \le 0 $$

The notation here could use some cleanup. For instance, your first integral has no infinitesimal.

@MathHanson you are absolutely right, I just followed Srivastava's notation assuming he knows what he meant by it.

Ah okay, that does make sense. May I ask if $\oint \Delta S = 0$ for all reversible or irreversible processes? From what I understood, the net entropy change should be greater than 0 for an irreversible cyclic process since the entropy change is a path function for an irreversible process. Oh, and the notation is the same as in my textbook "Thermodynamics: An Engineering Approach" by Yunus A. Cengel and Michael A. Boles

As long as entropy, or for that matter any other thermodynamic state quantity, such as internal energy, temperature, pressure, volume, etc.,  is definable in an irreversible process, it is a state variable so if the system returns to its original state in a cycle then the integral of its variation is zero; there is no variation, it is the same state. The entropy change is not a path function. Do not confuse the entropy of a state with the entropy generated by dissipation during the process. The generated entropy depends on the path and so does $\delta Q/T$ but their sum does not.

I see, I get it now. Thank you! The terms individually depend on the path but not the sum as a whole.
